# Different view controller at launch

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, appdelegate

I've got an app where I would like to display a tutorial on first launch. In order to I use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and it works fine. Here is how I implemented it in AppDelegate.m

```
    //Set windows
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //Set Storyboard
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle:nil];

    //Check if it's first launch or not
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        self.homeViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        self.rootVC = self.homeViewController;
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.tutoViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TutoViewController"];
        self.rootVC = self.tutoViewController;
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My problem is after the tutorial, when I push "HomeViewController", I've got a navigation bar with a back button. I thought about hidden it, but I think it's not really clean and i was wondering that it could be a better tricks.

Hope you'll help me!
Thx in advance

Comment: Why not push a modal view over the root view controller the first time the app is run?

Comment: I thought about it, but i've got the same problem when I use PresentViewController, after dismiss it, i've got a back button on nav bar.

Comment: If you're using a storyboard why not make it easy for yourself and delete the function above and use the storyboard to manage your views. Set a UINavigationController as the start view in the storyboard, add the first view controller you want as the root view controller by holding control and dragging to the root view control and then handle the modal popup logic in the viewWillAppear of your first view controller

Comment: Cool I added an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard why not make it easy for yourself and delete the function above and use the storyboard to manage your views. Set a UINavigationController as the start view in the storyboard, add the first view controller you want as the root view controller by holding control and dragging to the root view control and then handle the modal popup logic in the viewWillAppear of your first view controller